# the blank space below the <body> tag & script tag and link tag goes under body tag from head tag

Tags: php, html, utf-8, smarty, byte-order-mark

[image]

[image]

I wrote a php app using php+smarty.

When I view the web source code in firebug, I find that **link** tag and **script** tag get under the **body** tag. But it should be under the **head** tag.

And there are some space below **body** tag.

And there is  **blank space** on my top of my web page.

What is the problem?

Comment: Instead of that screenshot, just give us the HTML code of the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got some stray text content inside the `<head>`, before the `<link>` tag. The browser sees the text and decides this means you're starting the main document body but have forgotten to include the `<body>` tag.

This is actually valid—if inadvisable—in HTML4: the `<head>` end-tag and `<body>` start-tag are both optional. This is how you can have just `<html><head><title>x</title>Hello!` as a valid HTML document. But it's not permissible in XHTML, so if you [validate your document](http://validator.w3.org/) you should get a “character data is not allowed here” error at the point the stray text occurs.

The browser then parses the rest of the document as body content, putting the `<link>` inside the body (which is *not* valid, but which is nonetheless commonplace). It ignores the real `<body>` when that comes along because it already has a body.

If you can't see the stray text, perhaps it's an invisible character like U+00A0 No-break space   or—most likely for Chinese documents—U+3000 Ideographic space 　, which you may get when you press space in some input method modes. These characters won't be visible, but they're not ‘ignorable whitespace’ like a normal U+0020 Space or newline, so they trigger ‘text content’ processing and force the `<body>`.

Comment: i think that's the point , so how do i correct the error. after searching the web,they say maybe it's the problem of UTF-8 with BOM.

Comment: W3C markup Validator show the message:"Byte-Order Mark found in UTF-8 File.

The Unicode Byte-Order Mark (BOM) in UTF-8 encoded files is known to cause problems for some text editors and older browsers. You may want to consider avoiding its use until it is better supported. "

Comment: Yeah, it's a sensible warning and you should definitely get rid of the fake-BOM (save in your text editor as UTF-8-without-BOM), but it's not the cause of your problem here.

Comment: @bobince , Please check ur email box.i've send you the sample document.

Comment: The file you sent doesn't have any stray text and does not exhibit this behaviour (ending the `<head>` before `<link>` and consequently causing the gap) for me. It's not clear to me how the template could end up adding anything between the `</title>` and the `<link>`, either. What does the .html output look like?

Comment: @bobince the reason is that i'm using require_once() function of php in my index.php (index page handle script) include some class and library php file. these php file were using utf-8 with bom code. so the stray text appeared once i include one of these php files. And i view these files in hex mode , every file starts with EF BB BF which is the content of the stray text. LOL. also thx bobince for your clue.

Comment: Ah! Another include *inside* the `<head>`... yes, that would certainly do that. Man, I hate Microsoft's determination to drop faux-BOM turdlets by default in UTF-8 output.

Answer (score 1):

Blank spaces, specially at the start of the webpage are usually caused because the file is saved in the format UTF-8 (which contains BOM). If you are using an editor like Notepad++ or Vim, save the file in the format UTF-8 without BOM.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS:

```
html, body
{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: i've tried this,nothing changed. it seems that's not the problem of CSS.

Comment: as a matter of fact, i always start my layouts with * { margin: 0px; padding 0px } :D

Comment: Instead of a botch reset job like `*{margin:0;padding:0}` you really ought to be using a proper reset CSS file. There's a few out there :)

Answer (score 0):

Send your HTML through a validator ( http://validator.w3.org/ ) - it'll tell you what kind of error you've got in there (missing closing tag or something).